# If the union of two sets is uncountable, what may we conclude?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

I have $2$ questions. Here are these:

> 1) Assume that the union of sets $A$ and $B$ is uncountable. What exactly can we conclude from here?

I think, at least one of these sets is not countable. Or am I wrong? Or should both sets be uncountable?

> 2)  If the number of sets is more than $2$, will the result change?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is very elementary, but I wouldn't call it bad -- why the downvotes, with no explanatory comments?

Answer (score 2):

Assume a countable infinity of countable sets. You can pick elements from every set in a round-robin fashion, adding one set on every turn. This way, you enumerate all elements of all sets. So the union of countably many countable sets is countable.

Now add a single uncountable set. If that union was countable, the counting process would allow you to count the elements of the new set, a contradiction.

Comment: So at least one of these sets is not countable?

Comment: @Elementary: right.

Answer (score 0):

The question is designed in such a way so that you think inductively.

If $A_1\cup A_2$ has property $P$, then $Q$ is true.

If $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ has property $P$, then $Q$ remains true.

It is up to you to figure out what $Q$ is here when $P$ represents the property of being uncountable. I hope your assignment makes more sense now.

Comment: Unless you wrote that exercise, I think that the point is to note that an uncountable union of singletons is usually uncountable.